# Arranging data by occurrences

Tags: google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

Given a range with multiple items, I would like to count their occurrences and present the result as shown in this [Google Spreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goSM5n5QbpKdddQm1iwUSU_xTXKVRGaI-Av7RcugHOw/edit?usp=sharing) using just one formula, if possible.

This is the closest that I get:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''",0),"select Col1, Count(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2",0))
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Without having it as a single ArrayFormula it would be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ), "offset 1", ),,9^9)), " ", ))))
```

[image]

and:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ),,9^9)), " ")))
```

[image]

---

or joint:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ), "offset 1", ),,9^9)), " ", )));
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ),,9^9)), " "))})
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(IF(""=QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ), "offset 1", ),,"×"),,9^9)), " ", )));
 REGEXREPLACE(""&TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN( 
 IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(1/(1/(1*B3:U11)))), "!"&TEXT(B3:U11, "000000000#"), B3:U11))&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ),,9^9)), " ")), "^!0{1,9}", )})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Only with text it works perfectly, but if some items are numbers the result gets messed up. 
Can you please modify the formula having into account the presence of also numbers, showing the result in an ascending order (for both letters and numbers)?

Comment: Great! Thank you! It sorts the result, however the count is not right.

Comment: Using the first part of your formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(LEN(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ), "offset 1", ),,9^9))))
-
LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(B3:U11)&{"",""},
 "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) ''", ),
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2", ), "offset 1", ),,9^9)), " ", )))+1
);

        Please let me know if there is a faster way.

Comment: I apologize in advance if I should create a new question. If so, please let me know.

I need to present the zero-count in the result. There is a new sheet called "Desired result_2" for clarification.